# Load an png image file onto a dialog box in "C" at design time

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019

I have a call to a dialog box that comes up ok. But now I want to load an .png image onto the dialog box screen at design time.

I cannot seem to get it all together, and I do not have a solid understanding of how to do all this. Any help, sure be helpful.

Somewhere I read that I could move a copy of the png file onto the dialog box screen, all that appeared, when I did, was a large box with a little flower in the middle appeared.

Below is a copy of my dialog box function and function call.  All I want to do is just add a png image file onto the dialog screen and have it be shown; at design time and also have it during run time. Nothing fancy, but right to the point.

```c
       INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogXProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
          switch (uMsg) {
          case WM_COMMAND: {
            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
               case IDOK:     
    //// just falls thru...         
               case IDCANCEL:   
                   EndDialog(hwnd, LOWORD(wParam));
            }
            return 1;  
          }
          case WM_INITDIALOG: {
              SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL,
                  reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(LoadImage(0, IDI_APPLICATION, IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_SHARED)));
             ///ensure focus rectangle is properly draw around control with focus
             PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, 0, 0);
             return TRUE;
           }
           case WM_CLOSE:
             break;
          default:
             return FALSE;  
          }
      }

   INT_PTR returnval = DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOGKEPT), 0, 
     (DLGPROC)DialogXProcedure);
```